# How to disable systemd service starting on boot?

Tags: systemd, boot, reboot

I can't figure out how to ask systemd to not start specific service after reboot. I tried to disable service but I can't start it after disabling because my service's unit file is not located in /etc/systemd/system. I also tried to clear WantedBy. My configuration file:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=no
WorkingDirectory=/home/sentinel/arbitrage
ExecStart=/home/sentinel/arbitrage/venv/bin/python -m src.settings_bot.main
User=sentinel
Group=sentinel
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
Environment=DEV=
StandardOutput=append:/home/sentinel/arbitrage/settings-bot-log.txt
StandardError=append:/home/sentinel/arbitrage/settings-bot-log.txt

[Install]
WantedBy=
```

Comment: Where is the unit file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @memchr it's in home directory: /home/sentinel/arbitrage/systemd-units